# New to C++, Issues w/ String Equality using "=="

Tags: c++, string, object

I am somewhat new with C++. I have experience with Java and Python. In Java, there is a handy function ".equals()" to compare two strings. You do not of course use "==" in Java because that tests if two objects are exactly the same, I.E. have the same place in memory.

However, I am told on various websites including this one, that "==" is the preferred way of comparing two strings for equality. This seems fine if you simply want a statement to be executed if two strings are equal, hence

```
string one = "foo"
string two = "foo"

if (one == two)
{
    cout << "They are equal";
}
```

Things don't make quite as much sense when trying to use the same operator or "!=" to evaluate two strings and execute a statement if they are not equal.

I have tried doing this via ((first==second)==0) and (first != second) and the output is true (1). The program below should terminate once "DONE" is typed, yet this does not occur.

```
string first = "DONE";
string second = "";
while ((first==second)==0)
{
    cout << "Enter a line of text: ";
    cin >> second;
    cout << ((first==second)==0);
}
```

Comment: Typo? You're not changing `first` or `second` in the loop (only `line`), so of course they stay unequal.

Comment: For your information: if they are objects or references `&one == &two` would perform the test that they are the same object in memory, Java style. If they are pointers `string *one, *two` then `one == two` would test if they are the same object in memory and `*one == *two` would test they are only logically the same. (You must make sure they are not null in the last case)

Comment: http://ideone.com/HvyyCI

Comment: For the future: Please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you asked the wrong question by accident, just ask the right one in a new question.

Comment: Your code (as it currently appears) would work. If you seem to be having the problem still, please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show the input you provided to get the unexpected result.

Comment: I disagree with @BaummitAugen  , if the question contained typoes or did not reflect the intent it can be fixed.  Invalidated answers can be removed by their authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct operator is `!=`, and should work.

Here is the documentation on the string comparison operators: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

This should work:

```
string first = "DONE";
string second = "";
while (first != second)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course if you don't actually change second it will loop forever.

Comment: `first != second` is exactly equivalent to `(first == second) == 0` so this doesn't really shed any light on the problem

Answer (score 0):

You read to `line` instead of `second`.

If you still get trouble after that, print out what you are reading from stdin to make sure you don't just get a single character from stdin per call, or the newline at the end is included (or similar).

```
cout << "'" << second << "'\n";
```

BTW:

```
(first==second)==0
```

is the same as

```
(first==second)==false
```

which is the same as

```
first != second
```